# Using ctypes in Google App Engine to use Binaries?

Tags: python, go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to do interfacing between GoLang & Python. I have been a long time fan of Python and love using it. But Over Time I have udnerstood it is really bad for doing computations etc. Especially when there may be large data sets involved.

I have started learning golang mainly because of its speed, and was thinking of using it in my Application as a library. Writing Intensive Code in GoLang and then use methods in the libraries in Python for writing Beautiful High Level Application code in Python.

After doing the first prototype I deployed my code in GAE.

Unfortunately I hit this

```
from ctypes import *
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7,
  in <module> from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

I have read that GAE doesnt support ctypes out of the box for Python Instances. But is there a way I can circumvent this and use my Go Binaries and use them on GAE?

I followed this for my implementation and interfacing Go with Python https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify, but I'm guessing you're using the Python 2.7 runtime, which is heavily sandboxed. Using the Python 3.7 runtime (which is more idiomatic) should allow you to use ctypes.